# Sequelize: Add attribute column to query with where condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models, Posts and PostLikes. PostLikes contains a Username column that is associated with the User that liked the Post the Like is associated with.

I want to query all Posts but add an attribute which finds any PostLike with a Username I can pass in dynamically.

For example:

```
  const { Username } = req.data 

  const posts = await PostModel.findAll({
  attributes: [
    "id",
    "Username",
    "Title",
    "Body",
    "createdAt",
    "updatedAt",
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("PostLikes.PostId")), "LikeCount"],
    [
      sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("PostDislikes.PostId")),
      "DislikeCount",
    ],
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("PostLikes.Username")), "Liked"], // Right here I would like to see if there is a record in PostLikes for the Post.id, that equals a Username that I pass in.
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: PostLikeModel,
      attributes: ["Username"],
    },
    {
      model: PostDislikeModel,
      attributes: [],
    },
  ],
  group: ["Post.id", "PostLikes.id"],
  order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
});
```

Is there anyway to pass in the Username variable to add the attribute to each post found? I'm not sure if I'm wording this correctly. Sequelize is a pain to work with.

Edit: I tried adding as a literal:

```
    [
      sequelize.literal(
        `(SELECT * FROM "PostLikes" WHERE "Username" = ${Username})`
      ),
      "Liked",
    ],
```

Maybe this is progress as the error I am receiving now is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: column "testaccount" does not exist
```

Comment: Maybe use Sequelize.literal?

Comment: I tried it but am now receiving an error. I tried canceling \"${Username}\". Not sure if I'm doing it correctly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a where clause in your include, just like you can use it in findAll. If I understand your question correctly, this would be the way to go.

But keep in mind this will change your includes query from left join to inner join; meaning it will only fetch Post which has a PostLike.

Depending on your need you can pass a `required: false` attribute like I have in the example below. You may remove it if not necessary

```
const posts = await PostModel.findAll({
  attributes: [
    "id",
    "Username",
    "Title",
    "Body",
    "createdAt",
    "updatedAt",
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("PostLikes.PostId")), "LikeCount"],
    [
      sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("PostDislikes.PostId")),
      "DislikeCount",
    ],
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("PostLikes.Username")), "Liked"], // Right here I would like to see if there is a record in PostLikes for the Post.id, that equals a Username that I pass in.
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: PostLikeModel,
      attributes: ["Username"],
      where: {Username: 'YourValueHere'},
      required: false
    },
    {
      model: PostDislikeModel,
      attributes: [],
    },
  ],
  group: ["Post.id", "PostLikes.id"],
  order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
});
```

Comment: This adds a property to each post called "PostLikes" containing an array for each PostLike entry associated with the username.. so it kind of works. Do you know of any way to get either a true or false value showing whether a PostLike entry for that post exists? Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: This does work. So when a PostLike is found for the Username and Post the array will have a length of 1, if not it is empty. So, if nothing else I can just use the array length as an indicator.

Comment: I am not that fluent in Sequlize myself, but one way of doing that would be to iterate through the results returned and then add a property of true and false. Also, I think you would always have the property "PostLikes" as you were using include in your code as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll just use the length value as Tru/false until I can find another solution. Your were great help!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I just browsed through the Sequelize docs and there are methods for checking the existence of association and counting them, like hasPostLike() or countPostLike(). You can find more info here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances

Answer (score 0):

Update your literal from:

```
[
  sequelize.literal(
    `(SELECT * FROM "PostLikes" WHERE "Username" = ${Username})`
  ),
  "Liked",
],
```

to:

```
[
  sequelize.literal(
    `(SELECT * FROM "PostLikes" WHERE "PostLikes.Username" = ${Username})`
  ),
  "Liked",
],
```